# Wifi calling keeps getting turned off, how can I fix this?

Tags: calls, android-13

I need wifi calling for making calls when I'm inside. However in the settings menu it keeps getting turned off and I don't know why. I have Tasker but none of the tasks should be touching the setting. Any ideas on how I can get wifi calling to stay enabled? I have root.